# How to get the most recent data from firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I am writing a Twitter clone (but much simpler) with firebase database. A post contains only the message body. In the database, besides the message body, I also keep track of these things:

[image]

where `likeCount` is the number of likes on the post. It's incremented whenever someone likes the post. Posts are downloaded via `Cloud Functions`, because pagination is used and 10 posts are downloaded at a time. So, my question is, at the time of download, suppose each post has only 1 like, but if someone else likes a post, therefore, there should be 2 likes on the post now, how to I get this most recent `likeCount` without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android you should do like this to get the Updates of likeCount node

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
String postId="KyELxNpEaRt2Y64flUn"

database.getReference().child("posts/" + postId + "/likeCount").onChildChanged(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) 
{
if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
//here you should update the value
}
})
})
```

In React Native

```
 postRef=`/posts/${postId}/likeCount`;
 firebase.database().ref(postRef).on("child_changed", snap => {
    if (snap.val() != null) {
     //here you shold update the value
    }
  });
```